# SyntaxError: Unexpected token o at Object.parse (native) AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-http

Question from AngularJS noob.

I am trying to use an asmx web service to display grid. I tested the web service and it correctly outputs the JSON data.
Here is my controller

```
app.controller('SetupController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    var url = 'app/pricefilessetup/grid.asmx/getGridJson';

    $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
        var myjson = JSON.parse(data);
        $scope.products= JSON.parse(myjson);
    });
}]);
```

For some reason, SO is not allowing me to paste the html but it basically has a ng-controller directive and ng-repeat to loop through the JSON data.

When I run this web app, I get the error

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
and it points to following line

```
  $scope.questions = JSON.parse(myjson);
```

I tried checking the value of myjson using alert and it displays [object Object], [object Object], ...

Is there anything I am missing here

Comment: I doubt you need to ever use `JSON.parse`. Angular expects the response to be JSON by default and deserialises it for you.

Comment: Also, `alert` is a terrible debugging tool. Use `console.log` instead (or Angular's [`$log`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log) service)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think data returned is already in JSON, no need of `JSON.parse()`, unless it in string format.

```
$scope.products= data;
```

Answer (score 8):

Why you using `JSON.parse` in two times?

```
 var myjson = JSON.parse(data);
  $scope.products = JSON.parse(myjson);
```

You have already parse the data object,So then why you parsing another one time?

also i think your data is return Json result, so you don't need to parse the object

just use this

```
$scope.products = data;
```

Answer (score 7):

Your variable `myjson` is already a valid JavaScript Object. You do not have to use JSON.parse on it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, just use an absolute url:

```
var url = 'http://demo/app/pricefilessetup/grid.asmx/getGridJson';
```

Instead of using `var url = 'app/pricefilessetup/grid.asmx/getGridJson';`
I have checked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was string literal being passed in as parameter to `JSON.parse()`.

For Example `JSON.parse('asdf')` would throw an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a`.

With specific case, in Single page angular application, the access token was being passed to the `JSON.parse()` and clearing the cookies in browser solved the problem for me.